# LLDB How to load crashlog

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb, crash-log

I'm studying iOS crash analysis. Now, I need to import crashlog files into LLDB. As [WWDC18 Session 414](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/414/) said, I now have a copy of myApp, dSYM, xxx.crash.  Run the following command in **iTerm2.app**:

```
$ lldb
(lldb) command script import lldb.macosx.crashlog
(lldb) crashlog /path/xxxx.crash
```

However, the stack trace file is not available and there is only a lot of error like:

`error: unable to locate any executables from the crash log`

Did I use it wrong? What is the correct method of use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've recently had the same issue. Unfortunately, in it's current state the `crashlog` script appears to expect the original binary to be around, but we can "trick" it by either:

1. Copying the binary from inside the `.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/` into the path it is expecting it (found on the .crash file, something like `/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SOME-UUID/MyApp.app/MyApp`)
2. Editing the paths (not just the initial one) in the .crash file before symbolicating to the path of the binary (e.g. `~/MyFolder/MyApp.app/...`).

Hope this helps!